# multipart/form-data Possible?

Tags: authentication, jwt, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Google Cloud Endpoints with JWT Authorization and I am trying to Upload File from API.

There is no Issue with JWT as it is already working correctly with all other types ex. [application/JSON].

API POST Call (`api/document/processrequest`) with Content Type as `multipart/form-data` is saying Bad Format Response from Google Endpoints for Same Token.

API Post Call (`api/document/processrequest`) with ContentType (`application/JSON`) have no issues.

Is Google Cloud Point not supporting multipart/form-data?

Authorization Token is passed in Header. Authorization: Bearer [Token]

Everything works fine in Localhost/Development Environment without Endpoint.

Error Generated In Stackdriver Log:

> [image]

Firebug error sample call:

> [image]

Firebug success sample call with application/json:

> [image]

I have specified `application/JSON` and `multipart/form-data` both in openapi specification.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoints does not support multipart/form-data.